# Salesforce Security Review documentation

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, security, security-review

I want to know if their is any proper documentation format that I have to follow for security review.

I have searched for the document format and got this link
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info#3._Documentation

But any one please provide me a sample document so that I can use it for reference.

Comment: Even I have the same Issue. Please can anyone provide me a sample doc. that would be really great Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When you click the 'submit for security review button you will be presented with an online questionnaire. Fill that out and you will have provided the necessary information. Please also remember to check that credentials work and that your test org/website is pre-populated with sufficient sample data to exercise all of the interfaces.